# Git won't fast-forward merge even though the two branches should be in sync

Tags: git, merge, fast-forward

I have two branches, `dev` and `next`, where `next` was branched off `dev`. The branches diverged a little so when I made a hotfix to `dev` I merged the updates into `next` with a merge commit as expected. The latest commits on the branches looked like:

```
// dev
123455 Latest dev commit
123454 Earlier dev commits...

// next
123456 Merge branch 'dev' into next
123455 Latest dev commit
123454 Earlier dev and next commits...
```

Now I've made one more commit to `dev`, but when I try to merge it into `next` with `git merge --ff-only dev` it says a fast-forward is not possible. How can this be the case, when the branches were just in sync?

Comment: Try rebasing `next` on top of `dev` just to make sure they share a common history of commits before `next` diverted (i.e. `git rebase -i dev` while on the `next` branch).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you merged `dev` into `next`, you are only bringing `next` up-to-date with `dev`, but you have not changed `dev` at all. This means that `dev` does not have all of `next`s changes.

Fast-forwarding would move the `next` branch to point to exactly the same commit as `dev`, but this will cause you to lose you `next` changes, so it will not work.

```
A - B - C <- dev
 \       \
  D - E - F <- next
```

In my example, `dev` contains A,B, and C, while `next` contains A, B, C, D, E, and F. Therefore, you cannot merge `dev` into `next` without a merge commit because you will lose D, E, and F.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a better method of keeping my "next" branch up to date with bugfixes from dev besides creating merge commits all over the place?

Comment: Assuming that next is a branch that will not be included in any other branches until it is ready to be merged to master, just do `git rebase dev`. which will replay all your commits. See the documentation for more.

Comment: But unless I'm mistaken, you can't rebase when your commits have been published elsewhere (for example, all the changes to dev and next pushed to Github).

Comment: There is _can't_, and then there is _shouldn't_. You can rebase whatever you want. It is not usually a good idea if it has been published. If, however, noone is going to be basing any commits off of your published change, there is nothing to terrible to worry about other than causing you to force push and anyone who viewed the branch to force fetch. If you want to avoid even that then give your branch a new name, if possible. If anyone has committed on top of your changes, though, then you should merge.